# Splitting a frame into a grid and combining again, program closing instantly (C++, OpenCV 2.4.11)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm attempting to split each frame of a video stream into a 10x10 grid, which I have done. After I've done some operations I then stitch them back together, this all appears to be working. My problem is that the program will not stay open at all I see a single frame and then it terminates.

If I use waitKey(0) then I get 1 frame to freeze on the screen but I want a constant stream. Any help would greatly appreciated been stuck on this for over a day.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

 namedWindow( "Grid", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    VideoCapture cap;
    if (argc==1) {
        cap.open(-1);
    } else {
        cap.open(argv[1]);
    }
    if( !cap.isOpened() ) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open capture." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Width: " << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << std::endl;
    Mat frame, img_gry, img_gry_color;
    int a = 0;
    Mat imagesmall[100];
    vector<Mat> img_gry_vec;
    cv::Size sb_size(64,48);
    for(;;) {
        cap >> frame;
        if ( frame.empty()) {

            break;
        }
          for  ( int y = 0; y < 480; y += sb_size.height )

          {
            for  ( int  x= 0 ; x < 640; x += sb_size.width )
            {
                imagesmall[a] = Mat(frame, Rect(x,y,(sb_size.width), (sb_size.height))).clone();
                img_gry_vec.push_back(imagesmall[a]);
                a++;
            }
          }
        cv::Mat combined(480,640, img_gry_vec[0].type());
        a = 0;
          for  ( int y = 0; y < 480; y += sb_size.height )
          {
            for  ( int  x= 0 ; x < 640; x += sb_size.width )
            {
                  cv::Mat roi = combined(cv::Rect(x,y,sb_size.width,sb_size.height));
                  img_gry_vec[a].copyTo(roi);
                  a++;
            }
          }
        cv::imshow("combined" , combined);

        img_gry_vec.clear();
        if ( cv::waitKey(33) >= 0)
                        break;


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Edit: I've narrowed it down to something to do with

```
 cv::Mat combined(480,640, img_gry_vec[0].type());
    a = 0;
      for  ( int y = 0; y < 480; y += sb_size.height )
      {
        for  ( int  x= 0 ; x < 640; x += sb_size.width )
        {
              cv::Mat roi = combined(cv::Rect(x,y,sb_size.width,sb_size.height));
              img_gry_vec[a].copyTo(roi);
              a++;
        }
      }
    cv::imshow("combined" , combined);
```

Comment: "int key = waitKey(33); cout << key; if(key >= 0) break;" What's the value of key?

Comment: Key value is -1

Comment: try `if (waitKey(33)) break;` if that doesn't work, try `if (waitKey(33)=='q') break;`. In the latter scenario, you force user to press `q` to exit.